# How to indicate the last line of the file

Tags: c, arrays

I want to read the txt line by line and store it to the array;
I am like success to store line by line in array;
I use  `printf("%s", loadtext[i])` with `i= 0,1,2,3-20` respectively to check that things in stored in array;
but I realize that the for loop had done 1912 times when I 
type `printf("%d", i);` right behind the for loops,

Suppose my txt is store like this:

```
I am a jerk
I am a noob

I am an idiot
I am done
```

I have another program to add new lines to the text file while this program is running.
How can I detect `I am done` or the new line added later is the last line to not allow the for loop do so many times?

Here is my code

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <string.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp = fopen("abc.txt","r");
    int i = 0,j=0,k=0;
    char ch[10000];
    char loadtext[100][100];
    for (i=0; ch[i] != EOF; i++){
        ch[i] = fgetc(fp);
        if (ch[i] != '\n'){
            loadtext[j][k] = ch[i];
            k++;
        }
        if(ch[i] == '\n'){
            loadtext[j][k] = ch[i];
            k=0;
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", loadtext[0]);
    printf("%s", loadtext[1]);
    printf("%s", loadtext[2]);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184549/discussion-on-question-by-antonymous-how-to-indicate-the-last-line-of-the-file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read a whole file into an "array" of pointers to char which represent the lines, you can do:

```
#include <stddef.h>  // size_t
#include <stdlib.h>  // EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE
#include <stdio.h>   // malloc(), realloc(), free(), fgets()
#include <string.h>  // strlen(), strcpy()

enum { BUFFER_SIZE = 30 };  // whatever line length you suspect the input file to be + 1

int main(void)
{
    char const *filename = "test.txt";
    FILE *is = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!is) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open \"%s\" for reading :(\n\n", filename);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int result = EXIT_SUCCESS;  // assume a happy ending
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    size_t num_lines = 0;
    char **lines = NULL;

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), is)) {
        ++num_lines;
        char **temp = realloc(lines, num_lines * sizeof(*lines));
        if (!temp) {
            fputs("Not enough memory :(\n\n", stderr);
            fclose(is);
            result = EXIT_FAILURE;
            goto cleanup;
        }
        lines = temp;

        size_t length = strlen(buffer);
        length = strlen(buffer);

        // remove a trailing newline if any:
        if (length && buffer[length - 1] == '\n')
            buffer[--length] = '\0';

        size_t line_length = length;
        lines[num_lines - 1] = malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(*lines));
        if (!lines[num_lines - 1]) {
            fputs("Not enough memory :(\n\n", stderr);
            fclose(is);
            result = EXIT_FAILURE;
            goto cleanup;
        }

        strcpy(lines[num_lines - 1], buffer);

        // as long as the buffer has been filled completely by the previous
        // call to fgets() and a next call to fgets() also succeeds:
        while (length == BUFFER_SIZE - 1 && fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), is)) {
            length = strlen(buffer);

            // remove a trailing newline if any:
            if (length && buffer[length - 1] == '\n')
                buffer[--length] = '\0';

            char *temp = realloc(lines[num_lines - 1], line_length + length + 1);
            if (!temp) {
                fputs("Not enough memory :(\n\n", stderr);
                fclose(is);
                result = EXIT_FAILURE;
                goto cleanup;
            }
            lines[num_lines - 1] = temp;
            strcpy(lines[num_lines - 1] + line_length, buffer);
            line_length += length;
        }
    }
    fclose(is);

    // use lines:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_lines; ++i)
        puts(lines[i]);

cleanup:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_lines; ++i)
        free(lines[i]);
    free(lines);
    return result;
}
```

#### Using only a fixed-size two-dimensional array and fgetc()<sup>*)</sup>:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAX_LINES = 100, MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 100 };

int main(void)
{
    char const *filename = "test.txt";
    FILE *is = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!is) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open \"%s\" for reading :(\n\n", filename);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char text[MAX_LINES][MAX_LINE_LENGTH + 1] = { 0 };  // zero-initialize the array
                                                        // so we don't have to care
    size_t num_lines = 0;                               // about zero terminating
    size_t current_column = 0;                          // every line

    int ch;
           // as long as we are still inside the bounds of the fixed size array
           // and fgetc() doesn't return EOF
    while (num_lines < MAX_LINES && current_column < MAX_LINE_LENGTH &&
           (ch = fgetc(is)) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == '\n') {    // "move" num_lines and current_column to the next
            ++num_lines;     // line.
            current_column = 0;
            continue;
        }

        text[num_lines][current_column++] = ch;
    }

    if (ch != EOF) {
        fputs("The file is too big :(\n\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= num_lines; ++i)
        puts(text[i]);
}
```

*) Could be done with `fgets()` too.

Comment: what you are doing is giving a Maximum line to the array and the loop stop when the loop reaches the max line? @Swordfish

Answer (score 0):

> to read the txt line by line and store it to the array

Code has various problems:

- `ch[i] != EOF` accesses `ch[i]` before it is assigned!  Undefined Behavior (UB).
- `char` can be signed or unsigned.  `EOF` is some negative.  When `char` is unsigned the below is an infinite loop.  When `char` is signed, `ch[i] != EOF` could exit the loop early.
- `printf("%s", loadtext[0]);` attempts to print `loadtext[0]` as if it was a *string*.  But lacking a certain *null character*, and thus not a *string*, this leading to more UB.
- Lack of buffer index checks:  `loadtext[j][k] = ch[i]; k++;` may increment `k` to beyond 100.  Similar weak code with `i`.
- Code may fail to open the file and no check provided.

---

Instead save the result from `fgetc()` as an `int`, test for for `EOF`, test for `'\n'` and append a *null character* to form *strings*.

Some ideas for alternate code:

```
#define LINES_N 100
#define LINE_SIZE 100

int main(void) {
  FILE *fp = fopen("abc.txt", "r");
  if (fp) {
    // char ch[10000];
    char loadtext[LINES_N][LINE_SIZE];
    int ch_index = 0;
    int line_count = 0;
    int character;
    int previous_character = '\n';

    while ((character = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
      // Starting a new line?
      if (previous_character == '\n') {
        if (++line_count > LINES_N) {
          printf("Too many lines\n");
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
      }
      loadtext[line_count - 1][ch_index++] = (char) character;
      loadtext[line_count - 1][ch_index] = '\0';
      if (ch_index + 1 >= LINE_SIZE) {
        printf("Too long a line\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
      previous_character = character;
    }

    if (line_count >= 1) printf("%s", loadtext[0]);
    if (line_count >= 2) printf("%s", loadtext[1]);
    if (line_count >= 3) printf("%s", loadtext[2]);
    fclose(fp);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what if I change it to while loop like `while(ch[i] != EOF){.......; i++;}` @chux

Comment: Beware of testing EOF on something assigned to a `char` — the test either always fails (because plain `char` is an unsigned type) or sometimes fails prematurely (because plain `char` is a signed type, and 0xFF then matches EOF; not a problem in valid UTF-8, fortunately, but that's a substantial digression).

Comment: True code could avoid the _null character_ assignment be zeroing `loadtext[]`.  I see that as a good trade off in performance O(100x100) vs. O(number_of_characters read).  Better code would forego OP's fixed array.