# How to get a user input to open a file in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, stdin

So I'm trying to open a file based on a users input but I just keep getting what I typed in back.

This is what I have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
  FILE* data;
  char a[144];
  printf("Enter a filename:\n");
  fscanf(stdin, "%143[^\t]", a);
  data = fopen(a, "r");
  printf("%s", a);
  fclose(data);
  return 0;
}
```

This is my text file.

```
larry snedden 123 mocking bird lane
sponge bob 321 bikini bottom beach
mary fleece 978 pasture road
hairy whodunit 456 get out of here now lane
```

Comment: I need to display what's in the file to user once they're done entering in the filename.

Comment: You open the file but you actually forget to *read* from it. You simply print the file name again. (That said, you probably want to add a test if the file was successfully opened so ewhere.)

Comment: Okay. How can I do that?

Comment: `fscanf(stdin, "%143[^\n]", a);` If you use `[^\t]` you will read and include the trailing newline -- which is not what you want. (in addition to not reading from `data`)

Comment: Okay I modified that but I'm not understanding how to read from data.

Comment: "Read from a file"? That is best learned from another source. It is very, very basic C. From your previous questions, I get the impression you are attempting to learn by assimilation, rather than taking any recommended structured course. Learning an entire language step by step is not what's Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: That's not what i'm trying to do. I'm taking a course but my teacher didn't explain this in class. I know it's basic. I know how to do this when I can use the file name but I don't know how to do it using a user input.

Answer (score 4):

You face three primary issues: (1) you take a filename from the user with `fscanf(stdin, "%143[^\t]", a);` which will read all characters not a `tab` (including the trailing `'\n'` generated by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>), (2) after opening the file input by the user and assigning the return from `fopen` to `data`, you have no way to know whether the file is actually open (given the trailing `'\n'` included in the filename, I suspect it fails); and (3) you never actually read from the file-stream `data` (which is probably a good thing given you failed to **VALIDATE** it was actually open.

The key is to **validate every critical step** in your program **especially every bit of user input**. Each function provides a return -- **use them to validate** whether the function succeeded or failed.

A short example adding validation (and declaring a constant where needed -- don't use *magic numbers* in your code except where absolutely required -- like with the `scanf` *field-width* modifier), e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* if you need a constant, define one (or more)
                           ( don't SKIMP on buffer size ) */

int main (void) 
{
    FILE* data = NULL;  /* initialize all variables */
    size_t nlines = 0;
    char a[MAXC] = "";

    printf("Enter a filename: ");

    /* VALIDATE EVERY SINGLE BIT OF INPUT */
    if (fscanf (stdin, " %1023[^\n]", a) != 1) {
        fputs ("user canceled input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    /* open/VALIDATE file open for reading */
    if ((data = fopen (a, "r")) == NULL) {
        perror ("fopen-a");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("file opened: %s\n\n", a);

    /* reuse buffer to read each line */
    while (fgets (a, MAXC, data) != NULL)
        /* fgets include '\n' in buffer if buffer of sufficient size */
        printf ("line[%3zu]: %s", nlines++ + 1, a);
    fclose(data);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/file.txt
larry snedden 123 mocking bird lane
sponge bob 321 bikini bottom beach
mary fleece 978 pasture road
hairy whodunit 456 get out of here now lane
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fopen_file_from_user
Enter a filename: dat/file.txt
file opened: dat/file.txt

line[  1]: larry snedden 123 mocking bird lane
line[  2]: sponge bob 321 bikini bottom beach
line[  3]: mary fleece 978 pasture road
line[  4]: hairy whodunit 456 get out of here now lane
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `fgets()` to read a whole line of input:

```
#include <stddef.h>  // size_t
#include <stdlib.h>  // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <stdio.h>   // FILE, fprintf(), fputs(), fgets(), fopen(), fclose()
#include <string.h>  // strlen()

enum { MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH = 120 };

int main(void)
{
    char filename[MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH + 2]; // + '\n' + '\0'
    if (!fgets(filename, sizeof(filename), stdin)) {
        fputs("Input error :(\n\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t length = strlen(filename);  // get rid of the newline at the end:
    if (length && filename[length - 1] == '\n')
        filename[--length] = '\0';

    // When the length of the string is not needed, the above if-statement
    // can be replaced as suggested by Jonathan Leffler:
    filename[strcspn(filename, "\n")] = '\0'

    FILE *input = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(!input) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open \"%s\" for reading :(\n\n", filename);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // do stuff with input

    fclose(input);
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564875/how-to-indicate-the-last-line-of-the-file/53565160#53565160) on how to read a whole file into memory line by line.

Comment: It's often simpler to zap the newline by writing `filename[strcspn(filename, "\n")] = '\0';` instead of three lines and the conditions and decrements etc.  Using `strcspn()` works as long as there is a string in `filename`, even if it is empty.  Sometimes having the length is useful, of course — but you don't use it here.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, I added that as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

`fscanf(stdin, "%143[^\t]", a)` read input end with tab. You can try another method. And you didn't read from the file stream `data`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) 
{
   FILE* data;
   char a[144];
   printf("Enter a filename:\n");
   fscanf(stdin, "%s", a);  //use %s not 143[^t]
   data = fopen(a, "r");

   //read from the file
   char read_from_file[100];
   while (!feof(data)) {
       fgets(read_from_file, 1024, data);
       printf("%s", read_from_file);
   }
   print("\n")

   printf("%s", a);
   fclose(data);
   return 0;
}
```

text file named **file.txt**:

```
larry snedden 123 mocking bird lane
sponge bob 321 bikini bottom beach
mary fleece 978 pasture road
hairy whodunit 456 get out of here now lane
```

**input**:

```
file.txt
```

**output**:

```
larry snedden 123 mocking bird lane
sponge bob 321 bikini bottom beach
mary fleece 978 pasture road
hairy whodunit 456 get out of here now lane
file.txt
```